# Global Loading Flag for Apollo Client

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

Is there a global `loading` flag available anywhere for react-apollo client? I have a “page wrapper” component that i’d like to apply ui effects to after all the child components have received their data.

I have set up apollo with redux so have ready access to the store (http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html)

I could quite easily `dispatch` state changes from each component that receives data from apollo but I'd like this `page wrapper` component to not have any knowledge of its children nor their queries.

I have investigated using `withApollo` - http://dev.apollodata.com/react/higher-order-components.html#withApollo -
 but don't see an api for a global `is loading`.

Comment: I suspect you could wrap withApollo with a HoC and add in your custom logic in there.

Comment: i'm at a loss whether `withApollo` offers any API for a global `loading` status? I thought perhaps via its `networkInterface` but not looking like it could?

Comment: it does not out of the box.  you could achieve it with a custom network interface but that seems like the wrong tool for the job.  I suspect wrapping withApollo with something like withCustomApollo, you could check the loading state there.

Comment: But this isn't for any one specific component - i would like a separate component to be made aware of whether any graphql call at all is being made - unless i'm mistaken only the `graphql()` wrapped components themselves would receive the `data`/`loading` props

Comment: oh, then you can definitely use a custom network interface. Wrap the network interface (either the batch or the default) then whenever it queries set that it is loading to a singleton variable.

Comment: you may also be to achieve it using a middleware on the network interface rather then doing what I described in the previous comment. you'll have to experiment figure out what's best for your use case.

Comment: Ah yes, this all sounds very plausible. I'm giving it a go with an `middleWare/afterWare` combination to keep a tally of unresponded calls - any idea of how to map a request to a response - my graphql protocol knowledge is a little sketchy here. Surely it's possible - apollo client matches them somehow

Comment: This gist here suggests that request headers are persisted to response somehow so i'm good to go i think - https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/657#issuecomment-258440056

Have accepted your answer - middlewares are the way to go here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:

One way is to use the middleware/afterware of Apollo's network interface.

The other way is to wrap Apollo's network interface to include your custom logic.  Specifically you would wrap the query method.

Comment: can you explaing a little more? where can I read more about these method? like codesandbox code samples or documentations or github repo explaining this?

Comment: My comment was from 5 years ago but with the latest version of Apollo, I believe you could create a `new ApolloLink()` that sets a global loading value to true/false depending on if a result has been received or not.. and then have a global function like `getApolloLoading` that updates the state in zustand or redux. But, if you need it to be aware of react state, you may want to initialize the ApolloClient and <ApolloProvider .../> inside your `<App />` component.

Comment: Do you have any sample code anywhere? I am using nuxtjs/apollo and I am using a local state loading and manually update it.  I was wondering is there anything builtin in apollo link that would do this on the side. Or is there a way to use axios with apollo link? like is it a package it uses under the hood?

Comment: I do not have any sample code.  You might have more luck posting a StackOverflow question or reddit.com/r/reactjs.  You can read the package.json of apollo's repos to see if it uses axios but it seems unlikely since it would be an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: thanks, I found '@nuxtjs/observable' gonna check it. then I just have to find how they make api calls in apollo client

Answer (score 5):

I've just released a library that solves this for Apollo 2: [react-apollo-network-status](https://github.com/molindo/react-apollo-network-status).

The gist is:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {ApolloClient} from 'apollo-client';
import {createNetworkStatusNotifier} from 'react-apollo-network-status';
import {createHttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';

const {
  NetworkStatusNotifier,
  link: networkStatusNotifierLink
} = createNetworkStatusNotifier();

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: networkStatusNotifierLink.concat(createHttpLink())
});

// Render the notifier along with the app. The
// `NetworkStatusNotifier` can be placed anywhere.
const element = (
  <Fragment>
    <NetworkStatusNotifier render={({loading, error}) => (
      <div>
        {loading && <p>Loading …</p>}
        {error && <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>}
      </div>
    )} />
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </Fragment>
);
const node = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(element, node);
```